# Error 234, more data is available, with RegQueryInfoKey and RegEnumValue

Tags: c, winapi, registry

I am trying to use `RegQueryInfoKey` to get the longest value and data´s size and then `RegEnumValue` to show all the values, but I am getting the 234 error value, which means "More data is available" when I run the app.

I am also using `malloc` to allocate `lpValueName` and `lpData` so I can use the sizes that `RegQueryInfoKey` gave me.

If i set `lpcchValueName` to 16383, for example, the app works just fine, but it no idea why it doesn't with the `lpcMaxSubKeyLen` value returned by `RegQueryInfoKey`.

The registry key has two string values:
[image: HKCU\WinSide string values]

What am I doing wrong? Apologize for all the noob errors you might see. Here is my code:

```
int wmain()
{
    //RegOpenKeyEx
    HKEY hKey = HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
    LPCWSTR subKey = L"WinSide";
    DWORD options = 0;
    REGSAM samDesired = KEY_QUERY_VALUE;
    HKEY hkOpenResult;

    //Opening the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\WinSide subkey
    LONG openKey = RegOpenKeyEx(hKey, subKey, options,
                            samDesired, &hkOpenResult);

    if (openKey != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        wprintf(L"Error code: %li\n", openKey);
    else
    {
        wprintf(L"Key opened!\n");

        //RegQueryInfoKey
        LPWSTR pClass = NULL;
        LPDWORD pcClass = NULL;
        LPDWORD reserved = NULL;
        DWORD numberOfSubKeys;
        LPDWORD pcMaxSubKeyLen = NULL;
        LPDWORD pcMaxClassLen = NULL;
        DWORD numberOfValues;
        DWORD longestValueName;
        DWORD longestDataComponent;
        LPDWORD securityDescriptor = NULL;
        PFILETIME pLastWriteTime = NULL;

        //Querying info from HKCU\WinSide subkey
        LONG queryInfo = RegQueryInfoKey(hkOpenResult, pClass, pcClass, reserved, &numberOfSubKeys,
                                        pcMaxSubKeyLen, pcMaxClassLen, &numberOfValues,
                                        &longestValueName, &longestDataComponent,
                                        securityDescriptor, pLastWriteTime);

        if (queryInfo != ERROR_SUCCESS)
            wprintf(L"Error code: %li\n", queryInfo);
        else
        {
            wprintf(L"Key queried!\n");
            wprintf(L"Number of values: %u\n", numberOfValues);

            //RegEnumValue
            DWORD index=0;
            DWORD sizedem = sizeof(WCHAR);
            LPWSTR nameOfValue = (LPWSTR)malloc(longestValueName * sizeof(WCHAR));
            DWORD sizeOfBufffer = longestValueName;
            DWORD typeOfDataStored;
            LPBYTE pData = (LPBYTE)malloc(longestDataComponent * sizeof(BYTE));
            DWORD sizeOfData = longestDataComponent;

            if (nameOfValue != NULL && pData != NULL)
            {
                for (index = 0; index < numberOfValues; index++)
                {
                    sizeOfBufffer = longestValueName;

                    //Enumerating values from HKCU\WinSide subkey
                    LONG enuValue = RegEnumValue(hkOpenResult, index, nameOfValue,
                        &sizeOfBufffer, NULL, &typeOfDataStored,
                        pData, &sizeOfData);

                    if (enuValue != ERROR_SUCCESS)
                        wprintf(L"Error code: %li\n", enuValue);
                    else
                    {
                        wprintf(L"Value: %s\n", (LPWSTR)pData);

                    }

                }

            }
            else
            {
                wprintf(L"Memory could not be allocated.\n");
            }       



            free(nameOfValue);
            free(pData);


        }



        RegCloseKey(hkOpenResult);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

This is my result:

[image: Result]

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your code containing many errors.

1) 
`LPWSTR nameOfValue = (LPWSTR)malloc(longestValueName * sizeof(WCHAR));`

really longestValueName this is

> The size does not include the terminating null character.

so you need

```
LPWSTR nameOfValue = (LPWSTR)malloc((longestValueName + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR));
```

or (better)

```
LPWSTR nameOfValue = (LPWSTR)malloc(++longestValueName * sizeof(WCHAR));
```

then in loop, if use first variant - `sizeOfBufffer = longestValueName + 1`;

or as in your code, if use `++longestValueName`

2) `DWORD sizeOfData = longestDataComponent;`

you must do this in Loop, as and `sizeOfBufffer = longestValueName`; because `sizeOfData` will be changed after every `RegEnumValue`

3) and you must be ready, that until you enumerate key, somebody can change key data/values - so Maximum can increase - what you got in call `RegQueryInfoKey` is only reasonable hint but not 100% guarantee

Comment: Thanks a lot, master @RbMm! I am learning a lot from you and all the folks here!